# Let $P \sim Q$. Is it true that if (the r.v.) $X \in L^2(\Omega, \mathscr{F},P)$ then $X \in L^2(\Omega, \mathscr{F},Q)$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ be a probability space and X a square-integrable random variable. Suppose there is another probability Q equivalent to P. Is it true that X is also square-integrable with respect to Q? if not, can we impose a condition on the probability space or Q to make it true?

Comment: I think not : $\Omega=\mathbb N$ and $\mathscr F=2^{\mathbb N}$, let $X(\omega)=\omega$, let $P(n)=C_1\frac{1}{n^3}$ and $Q(n)=C_2\frac{1}{n^4}$, with $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that it sums to $1$. Then $P\sim Q$ and $\mathbb E_P[(X-\mathbb E_P[X])^2]=\infty$ and $\mathbb E_P[(X-\mathbb E_P[X])^2]<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. What about my second question? Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to take a look at Radon-Nikodym derivatives, Observe that $\mathbb E_Q[X^2]=\mathbb E\left[ \frac{dQ}{dP} X^2 \right]$, which means that it is finite if and only if $\mathbb E\left[ \frac{dQ}{dP} X^2 \right]$ is finite, by Cauchy Schwartz this happen for example when $\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac{dQ}{dP}\right)^2\right]$ and $\mathbb E[X^4]$are finite. I'm not sure about all this but you may be able to check it out.

Comment: Or maybe Holder's with $p\to \infty$ and $q\to1$, then if $\sup \frac{dQ}{dP}$ is finite, then your result follows. (This needs to be fixed, it doesn't work with my example above).

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out, thank you.